# How to show certificate with lock icon using InAppBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser, padlock

I am using InAppBrowser plugin in my cordova application to load url in WebView. I need to show padlock (lock) icon so user can click on that and can see certificate details. But I do not see any option in InAppBrowser plugin (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html).

Here's what I can see as of now:

[image: current]

Here what I am planning to show. Below example, I grab from Twitter. After clicking any url from Twitter, it shows page with padlock icon where you can check certificate details.

[image: twitter_sample]

Here is my code :

```
function openBrowser() {
   var url = 'https://cordova.apache.org';
   var target = '_blank';
   var options = "location = yes,hidenavigationbuttons=yes,closebuttoncaption= ,closebuttoncolor=#0000ff,lefttoright=yes,toolbarcolor=#000000"
   var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

   ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('loaderror', loaderrorCallback);
   ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);

   function loadstartCallback(event) {
      console.log('Loading started: '  + event.url)
   }

   function loadstopCallback(event) {
      console.log('Loading finished: ' + event.url)
   }

   function loaderrorCallback(error) {
      console.log('Loading error: ' + error.message)
   }

   function exitCallback() {
      console.log('Browser is closed...')
   }
}
```